# Roots of a polynomial in two variables are meromorphic functions.

Tags: complex-analysis

I came across the following statement:

> Let $P(z,w)\in\Bbb C[z,w]$ be an irreducible polynomial. Suppose that there is a holomorphic function $f\colon D\setminus\{0\}\to\Bbb C$ such that $P(z,f(z))=0$ for every $z\in D\setminus\{0\}$. Then $0$ cannot be an essential singularity of $f$.

A possible proof goes as follows:

> $P(0,w)=0$ has only finitely many zeros, say $w_1,\cdots,w_n$. If $|z|$ is small, then $f(z)$ must be close to some $w_i$. If $0$ is an essential singularity, then Casorati–Weierstrass theorem will gives us a contradiction.

**My Question**: why must $f(z)$ be close to some $w_i$ if $z$ is close to $0$?

I tried to use the fact that roots of polynomials continuously depends on their coefficients. However, I believe that this is true only for polynomials for some fixed degree. What if $\deg_wP(0,w)<\deg_wP(z_0,w)$ for $z_0\neq0$?

Can anybody shed some light on this question? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roots vary continuously as $z$ varies in the following sense they can hit together or separate, but they can't jump around.  For each fixed $z$, the function $w \mapsto P(z,w)$ is a holomorphic function.  Draw a small circle around one of the roots of $P(0,w)$ so that the circle does not hit any other root, and now use the argument principle.  Suppose the root is of multiplicity $N$, then if $C$ is the circle, then you have $2\pi i N = \int_C \frac{P_w(0,w)}{P(0,w)} dw$.  By continuity you get that for all small $z$, $2\pi i N = \int_C \frac{P_w(z,w)}{P(z,w)} dw$ (the integral is a continuous function into a discrete set, so constant).  The only way you'd get the number to change is if the function under the integral stopped being continuous, that is, if one of the roots of $w \mapsto P(z,w)$ happened to be on the circle $C$.  Now draw a large circle around all the roots, by argument principle you get that this integral is the sum of the small integrals around small circles around each of your roots.  Therefore, no other roots can "come into existence" outside the small circles, but inside the large circle.  Roots could have been "at infinity", and could start moving towards your big circle.  Your large circle is really just like your small circles except going around infinity in the other direction.  But the number of roots inside the large circle is constant for small $|z|$.

So if you pick $|z|$ small enough so that none of the zeros get out of their small circles, then $f(z)$ must be inside one of those circles if it was every near one of those roots.  Assuming that $f(z)$ has an essential singularity implies that in arbitrarily small neighborhoods of the origin it attains some roots that lie in the big circle.  Another way to think of it is that if $f(z)$ followed one of these roots that is eventually outside any large circle as $z$ goes to 0, then $|f(z)|$ goes to infinity and $f(z)$ has a pole at 0.

As an aside: Read up on Weierstrass preparation theorem.  It is most interesting for holomorphic functions of several variables, but it is useful even for polynomials.

Aside two: The hypothesis of irreducibility is quite strong.
All you need is for
$w \mapsto P(0,w)$ not to vanish identically (and so have finitely many zeros).  Therefore all you need is for the polynomial $P$ is not to be divisible by $z$.

Comment: $dw$ not $dz{}{}{}$

Comment: Nice argument! I'll think about it! Thanks!

Comment: After giving your argument a thought, there is a part I couldn't understand. So, multiplicities of roots of P(0,w) should add up to the degree of P(0,w), right? By continuity, in every small circle, the number of roots won't change, so they also add up to the degree of P(0,w). However, for nonzero z, the degree could be higher. So, why is it not possible that some zero is not in those circles?

Comment: There could be roots coming from infinity.  For small z, P(z,w) might have other roots, but they will be outside the big circle.  I will edit to make this clear.  E.g. P(z,w) = zw^2 + w.  Then there is a single zero at the origin, and as z goes away from the origin, a zero comes crashing down from infinity :)

Comment: After writing the last clarification it dawned on me that the clarification was for a different situation ($f$ continuous at the origin, which is obviously not the setting of the question).  So I fixed the clarification now to what I think I had originally in mind yesterday (that's a long time ago, I don't claim to remember what I was thinking precisely).  Basically if you have one of these zeros coming from infinity, then you have a pole.

Comment: Okay, I finally got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can write $P(z,w) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}q_k(z)w^k,$ where the $q_k$ are polynomials and $q_n \not \equiv 0.$ For any $f$ holomorphic in a region in the plane we then have $P(z,f(z)) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}q_k(z)f(z)^k.$

Suppose $f$ has an essential singularity at $0$ and $P(z,f(z))\equiv 0$ in a punctured disc. Then $q_nf$ has an essential singularity at $0,$ so there is a sequence $z_j \to 0$ along which $f$ is nonzero and such that $q_n(z_j)f(z_j)\to \infty.$ Dividing by $f(z_j)^{n-1},$ we get

$$q_n(z_j)f(z_j) = -\sum_{k=0}^{n}q_k(z_j)f(z_j)^{k-n}$$

for all $j.$ That's a contradiction because the left side $\to \infty,$ while the right side $\to 0.$

Comment: why the member on the right side to $0$?